# Why don't keyboard keys work in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I wanted to select an element through keyboard keys in Firefox. I am using this statement

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("Element')]")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

But when I run it, I couldn't see any movement in the page. I am using JAVA to automate. This issue occurs even in BEHAT\MINK Tool.

My doubt:

1. is this feature not working because of the developers code?
2. or I need to modify my code to make it work?

Comment: Check this page for scrolling using Selenium WebDriver: http://seleniumworks.blogspot.com/2013/08/page-scroll-using-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: Perform a click operation in some part of the page before you use keys class. Sometimes manually as well as soon as the page opens and if you have not got the focus of the pointer by clicking on some part of the page your key board keys will not work. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scrolling page up/down, you can send keys on `body` tag element of the page, like following:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.UP); //to scroll up
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN); //to scroll down
```

Comment: I think author wanted "...to select an element through keyboard keys". I think it is like tabbing through elements not scrolling the whole page.

Comment: Hm... initially, I was also confused what the author wants to achieve actually.